# Adding properties to Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, object, properties

myTable.div will return "div_undefined". When I'm changing `div: 'div_' + this.name` to `div: 'div_' + myTable.name` it will throw an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at :3:26

. Any Ideas?

```
var myTable = {
   name: 'tablename',
   div: 'div_' + this.name
}
console.log(myTable.div);
```

Comment: Add more code to know what `this` refers to.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I think he/she refers `this` for myTable object

Comment: We need more context. Also please say _which_ error is thrown. Better yet, post the full reproduction.

Comment: do something like the following


`var myTable = {
   name: 'tablename',
   div: ''
}`

`myTable.div='div_'+myTable.name`

Comment: Solved by @Quentin through referencing to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Answer (score 1):

You can first declare your `object` then add the `div` property:

```
myTable.div = 'div_' + myTable.name;
```

Keep in mind that `objects` can be always extended with more `properties`, if you check the **[MDN `Object` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Properties)** you can see that:

> In JavaScript, **objects can be seen as a collection of properties**. With the object literal syntax, a limited set of properties are initialized; **then properties can be added and removed**.

**Demo:**

```js
var myTable = {
  name: 'tablename'
};
myTable.div = 'div_' + myTable.name;
console.log(myTable);
```